# I want to run a GIPHY or similar in an outlook email

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, giphy

I would like to run a GIPHY in an outlook email, which automatically starts when the user opens the email in their inbox.

Currently this is not possible in outlook 2013 as Microsoft disabled the functionality (They now use word as a text editor which does not read HTML). Users can view the email through a web browser but I don't want to have to ask them that!

My question is, is there an alternative to a GIPHY which I can run in an outlook email so that I can get a moving image, without the user viewing through the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook isn't capable of displaying animated GIF files. It doesn't work with web video either.

My suggestion is to set up your animated image so the first frame conveys the message you're trying to send.

If the viewer clicks on the image and views it in a browser window, it will work.

You could add a message for Outlook viewers on how to load an animated gif image.

```
 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>If you have Outlook, jump through hoops!<![endif]-->
```

Good luck.